# Local IndexedDB security (DB name uniqueness)

Tags: javascript, html, pouchdb

PouchDB uses IndexedDB under the hood. You specify a database name when you create it; if it's not a URL, [the docs](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database) mention that `it will create a local database using whatever backend is present (i.e. IndexedDB, WebSQL, or LevelDB).`

What I can't find is any information about the uniqueness of the name. If there are two web applications that create an IndexedDB with the same name, what happens?

Is it that:

- The DB is linked to the domain, so you only need unique database names within multiple web applications (eg. games) on a single domain, or
- The DB name is global, and all databases must have unique names (similar to how Google Play requires unique app namespaces)

I plan to use this in multiple games hosted on a single domain, but I also want to know if Is should prefix some domain identifier in the DB names so I don't accidentally collide with other IndexedDB instances from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

WebSQL and IndexedDB databases are both linked to the host. So `foo.com` and `bar.com` would have different databases, even if they gave them the same name. It's standard web security; the same thing happens with cookies and LocalStorage.

From the [Cross Directory Attacks](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#cross-directory-attacks) section:

> Different authors sharing one host name, for example users hosting content on geocities.com, all share one set of databases.

So apparently databases are shared per-domain but not per-host.

Comment: I thought so too, but couldn't find any supporting evidence that can prove this. Can you point me to some docs/specs that say essentially this?

Comment: That's quite a lengthy document. I read through some of it, but couldn't find the part you referenced. Can you reference and quote the relevent excerpt in your answer please?

Comment: "Different authors sharing one host name, for example users hosting content on `geocities.com`, all share one set of databases."

The exact same text is actually in both documents. So apparently databases are shared per-domain but not per-host. Sorry for the mistake; I didn't actually look it up until now. :)